# use collect() and env.execute() in one flink job

Tags: apache-flink, gelly

I'm trying to write a computation in Flink which requires two phases.

In the first phase, I create a Graph and get its vertex ids:

```
List<String> ids = graph.getVertexIds().collect();
```

In the second phase, I'd like to use these ids to run SingleSourceShortestPath for each vertex.

```
for (String id: ids){
        System.out.println("Source Id: "+id);
        graph.run( new SingleSourceShortestPaths<String, String>(id, 10)).print();
    }
```

It works locally (in IntelliJ IDE and command lines using `./bin/flink run ...`), but when I submit the job on Flink using its WebUI, the program just execute till `collect()` method and does not run the remaining of the program (for statement and `print()`).

What is the problem?

Here is my code:

```
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.MapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.graph.Edge;
import org.apache.flink.graph.Graph;
import org.apache.flink.graph.library.SingleSourceShortestPaths;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        Edge<String, Double> e1 = new Edge<String, Double>("1", "2", 0.5);
        Edge<String, Double> e2 = new Edge<String, Double>("2", "3", 0.5);
        Edge<String, Double> e3 = new Edge<String, Double>("4", "5", 0.5);
        Edge<String, Double> e4 = new Edge<String, Double>("5", "6", 0.5);
        Edge<String, Double> e5 = new Edge<String, Double>("7", "8", 0.5);


        List<Edge<String, Double>> edgeList = new ArrayList<Edge<String, Double>>();
        edgeList.add(e1);
        edgeList.add(e2);
        edgeList.add(e3);
        edgeList.add(e4);
        edgeList.add(e5);


        Graph<String, String, Double> graph = Graph.fromCollection(edgeList,
                new MapFunction<String, String>() {
                    public String map(String value) {
                        return value;
                    }
                }, env);

        List<String> ids = graph.getVertexIds().collect();

        for (String id: ids){
            System.out.println("Source Id: "+id);
            graph.run( new SingleSourceShortestPaths<String, String>(id, 10)).print();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [link](http://www.baeldung.com/apache-flink), Flink transformations are lazy, meaning that they are not executed until a ***sink operation*** is invoked.

A ***sink operation*** in Flink triggers the execution of a stream to produce the desired result of the program, such as saving the result to the file system or printing it to the standard output

The methods such as `Dataset.collect()`, `Dataset.Count()` and `Dataset.print()` are  sink operations that trigger the actual data transformations.